# TreeMap<DateTime, Object> is not sorting

Tags: java, android, datetime, dictionary

I have TreeMap using the Joda DateTime object and is does not seem to be sorting here is the definition:

```
TreeMap<DateTime, HolderAnswer> dateTimeTreeMap = new TreeMap<DateTime, HolderAnswer>();
```

I added in the values as follows (I'm just using a generic sql statement here);

```
            //then get previously selected answers to move to the top of the list
        String sql = "Select ActionDT, RecID, TextID, Text, Value from Foo";

        Cursor c = DataBaseConnector.query(sql);

        if (c != null) {
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {

                do {
                    HolderAnswer answer = null;
                    boolean valueAlreadyIn = false;
                    DateTime dt = formatter.parseDateTime(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("ActionDT")));
                    //we will be adding in the options in the next section, setting to null for now. 
                    answer = new HolderAnswer(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("RecID")),c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("TextID")),null,count,c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Text")));


                    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                    Iterator<Entry<DateTime, HolderAnswer>> it = dateTimeTreeMap.entrySet().iterator();
                    while (it.hasNext()) {
                        Entry<DateTime, HolderAnswer> pairs = it.next();
                        HolderAnswer tempAnswer = (HolderAnswer) pairs.getValue();
                        DateTime tempDateTime = (DateTime) pairs.getKey();
                        //if answers match, transfer over options
                        if (answer.getTextID() == tempAnswer.getTextID()) { 
                            valueAlreadyIn = true;
                        }
                    }
                    if (!valueAlreadyIn) {                           
                        dateTimeTreeMap.put(dt,answer);
                    }
                    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


                    //count++;

                } while(c.moveToNext());

                c.close();
                c = null;
            }
        }
```

When I print out the values, they don't seem to be sorted, they come out in no discernable pattern.  Even doing:

```
dateTimeTreeMap.descendingMap();
```

Does nothing.  Am I missing something?

Comment: What are the objects/classes that you trying to compare and sort ?

Comment: I am trying to sort by DateTime.

Comment: `Iterator<Entry<DateTime, HolderAnswer>> it = dateTimeTreeMap.entrySet().iterator();`  This will give an iterator that iterates in ascending order of keys ( DateTime here ).Can you show sample output of your run when you say its not in that order ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The descendingMap() method is used to **return** a reverse order view of the mappings contained in this map so  it looks like you're forgetting to assign the sorted map to the original one.

```
dateTimeTreeMap = dateTimeTreeMap.descendingMap();
```

Comment: I'm getting a classCast Exception when trying to do: dateTimeTreeMap = (TreeMap<DateTime, HolderAnswer>) dateTimeTreeMap.descendingMap();

Comment: Good, that's what I was about to suggest :P

Comment: If I helped solve your problem would you mind marking my answer as correct?